# How to change color on hover for a link in a tab?

Tags: css

I want to change to text of the links "Lesson List" and "Browse Q&A" on hover, which I got to do adding the following to the WordPress Add custom CSS menu:

```css
.tutor-tabs-btn-group a :hover {
    color: #000;
}
```

However, when hovering over the tab or icon, the changes do not apply. By inspecting it I can see the class is `tutor-tabs-btn-group`, and the specific links have the ID `#tutor-lesson-sidebar-tab-content` and `#tutor-lesson-sidebar-qa-tab-content` but targetting them doesn't seem to work.

I must say I have no idea about CSS, so I might be missing something really simple.

Here's the other code I have on Add Custom CSS, in case some can be conflicting with it:

```
a:not(.card):not(.btn-primary):not(.nav-link):not(.text-white):not(.dropdown-item):not(.btn-outline-primary):not(.btn):not(.elementor-button):hover, section:not(.text-light) .nav-link, footer:not(.text-light) .nav-link, .widget a {
    color: #fff; }

.tutor-single-lesson-wrap {
    background: #ffffff; }


.tutor-button-lesson-wrap {
    background: #ffffff; }

:root {
    --tutor-success-button-color: #000; }


.tutor-lead-info-btn-group .tutor-course-compelte-form-wrap button {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    background: #ad1519;
    color: #fff; }

.tutor-lead-info-btn-group .tutor-course-compelte-form-wrap button:hover {
    background: #ad1519;
    color: #fff; }

body.custom-background {
    background-color: #fff; }

.tutor-tabs-btn-group :hover {
    color: #000; }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to remove the space: `a:hover`

Comment: Thanks @Daniel_Knights, but I tried that and the result is that it doesn't even work when hovering directly on the text.

Comment: Is the class `tutor-tabs-btn-group` on the `a` link? If it is you can just remove the `a` altogether and have `.tutor-tabs-btn-group:hover`

Comment: Doing that makes it not work even when hovering directly on the link.

Comment: Could you make a working snippet of it? It's hard to say without one

Comment: However, if I add the space it works the same as when adding the `a`.

Comment: Sorry @Daniel_Knights I'm not sure what a working snippet is, much less how to create one. Have you had the chance to go to the URL to inspect it? I might me targeting the wrong class or ID. Let me research what a working snippet is and see if I can make one.

Comment: Click on the little `<>` icon in the question editor and add enough code to demonstrate the issue. You can read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for more info

Comment: Thanks, I am using the WordPress and its "Additional CSS" tool, so the code I posted in the question is all the code I made.

Comment: I checked the link and `Lesson List` is changing to `color: #000` for me

Comment: @Daniel_Knights But when you hover over the icon or next to the text, it does to? That's the problem, only when hovering directly on the text works.

Comment: Playing around in the devtools I have absolutely no idea why it's doing that, really strange. It only seems to work when you hover over the `span` and not the `a`

Comment: Is there no other code you could post which might be conflicting with it?

Comment: @Daniel_Knights I added to the question all the code I added to the custom CSS area on WP.

Comment: Okay, it's hard to tell but I think it's your first rule selecting all `a` tags which aren't certain classes. It's very long so I'd suggest removing that rule and only targeting the `a` tags you *want* to be `#ffffff` on hover. You also need to have `.tutor-tabs-btn-group a:hover` as the `a` is inside `.tutor-tabs-btn-group`. If you do both of these things, it should work

Comment: Ah! I think the first lines are the ones conflicting with it... Now I just need to figure out what they're doing haha. Thanks Daniel, I think now I am a bit closer to the issue.

Comment: Thanks, I will start playing with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will fix the issue

```css
.tutor-tabs-btn-group a:hover{
 color: #000 !important
}
```

`.tutor-tabs-btn-group a:hover` will apply `css` for `a` tag

```html
<element class="tutor-tabs-btn-group">
  …
    <a :hover>
```

And

`.tutor-tabs-btn-group a :hover` will apply `css` for inner elements of `a` tag

```html
<element class="tutor-tabs-btn-group">
  …
    <a>
      …
        <element :hover>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try to target a parent/wrap of your links, and then you can do:

```
.parentname a:hover {
 color: #000;
}
```

To find such a parent, you can right click on one of the links and select "Inspect Element". In the "style" tab of the Inspector you'll be able to see all the css rules applied to the element. You can test each of them live, by disabling or editing them.

Another possibility is that the links are not `a` links, but some kind of other html elements like `label`, turned into clickable elements by javascript. You can still change the css related to them, but in this case, don't look specifically for `a` selector. It could be something like:

```
.navigation label:hover {
 color: #000;
}
```

Good luck !